# Test config for AVA + React-Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, babeljs, ava

I try to test my react-native application using [AVA](https://github.com/sindresorhus/ava) and the [babel-preset-react-native](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/master/babel-preset)

My config looks like this:

```json
"scripts": {
  "test": "ava"
},
"ava": {
  "files": [
    "src/**/__tests__/*.js"
  ],
  "failFast": true,
  "require": [
    "react-native-mock/mock.js",
    "babel-register"
  ],
  "babel": {
    "presets": [
      "react-native"
    ]
  }
},
"devDependencies": {
  "ava": "^0.13.0",
  "babel-preset-react-native": "^1.2.4",
  "babel-register": "~6.4.3",
  "react-native-mock": "0.0.6"
}
```

…and fails like this:

```html
/Users/zoon/Projets/xxxxx/node_modules/babel-register/node_modules/babel-core/lib/transformation/file/index.js:556
      throw err;
      ^

SyntaxError: /Users/zoon/Projets/xxxxx/src/reducers/env.js: Unexpected token (12:8)
  10 |     case types.RECEIVE_CHANGE_ENV:
  11 |       return {
> 12 |         ...state,
     |         ^
  13 |         current: Environments[action.env]
  14 |       };
  15 |     default:
```

If I export this babel config in a .babelrc file and use "babel": "inherit" in my AVA config, it fails in an other way:

```html
/Users/zoon/Projets/xxxxx/node_modules/lodash-es/lodash.js:10
export { default as add } from './add';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
```

I can't understand how to correctly configure this. I've tried Mocha, encountered the same problems.

Comment: @zooontek, Where is `lodash-es` coming from? Is that one of your dependencies? If so, I recommend using straight `lodash` instead. ES2015 code should be compiled before deploying to `npm`, it avoids this sort of problem.

Comment: @JamesTalmage Yes, it's one of my dependencies. I could totally use lodash instead, but if I can't configure ES6 deps transpilation for testing, I loose all the flexibility of ES6 written libs and tree-shaking

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`babel-register` ignores `node_modules` by default. You can set `ignore:false` in your `.babelrc` to disable that behavior. You could (probably should) also specify a more limited regular expression to avoid processing *everything* in `node_modules`.

See the docs: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/require/

Your complete config should probably look something like this:

---

.babelrc

```
{
  "presets": ["react-native"],
  "ignore": false
}
```

---

package.json

```
{
  "ava": {
    "babel": "inherit"
  }
}
```

Comment: I ignored about this settings, thanks a lot. I may be a good idea to put this config in ava documentation, somewhere.

Comment: @zoontek - If this is the answer, could you please accept it?